# Can i use where condtiton after calling relation with @with method?

Tags: php, laravel

This code:

```
$users = Users::with(['posts' => function($post) use ($request) {
    $post->where('votes', '>', 100);
}])->get();

dd($users->toArray());
```

Return output like this:

```
0 => [
    "user_id" => 1
    "posts" => []
]
```

What can I do to return an empty array of users?
I tried to do like this:

```
$users = Users::with(['posts'])
    ->where('posts.votes', '>', 100)->get();

dd($users->toArray());
```

But got an error:

```
Undefined table: 7 ERROR: issing FROM-clause entry for table "posts"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the syntax you tried, the answer is "No", as `->with()` doesn't perform any kind of `join` logic; so `posts` tables is not available there.

If you want to filter the `User` records returned based on a condition of a relationship, you need to use one of `has()` or `whereHas()` method. In your case, since you're looking for `votes > 100`, with `votes` being a column, you need to use `whereHas()`:

```php
$users = Users::whereHas(['posts' => function($query) {
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}])->get();
```

This will limit the `User` record being returned to those that have 100 votes or more.

Additionally, you can use both `whereHas()` and `with()` with the same function to Filter and Eager Load the relationship (preventing extra queries from being run later). Syntax for that would be:

```
$closure = function ($query) {
  return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
});

$users = Users::whereHas(['posts' => $closure]
->with(['posts' => $closure])
->get();
```

Complete documentation is available here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use `whereHas` method. Can you try like this?

```
$users = Users::with(['posts'])
              ->whereHas('posts.votes', function($q){
                     $q->where('votes', '>', 100);
              })->get();

dd(optional($users)->toArray(), $users->toArray());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).